# рандомная картинка

Tags: python, tkinter

в коде снизу хочу вывести рандомно 1 картинку из 4, но все ли правильно? картинки не находит

```
import random
flags=[r"1.png",
        r"2.png",
        r"3.png",
        r"4.png"]
random.choice(flags)
photo = PhotoImage(file = flags)

Button(screen, image = photo).pack(side = TOP) 
mainloop()
```

Comment: Примите ответ, если на вас помог - галочка слева ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

random.choice(sequence) - возвращает случайный элемент непустой последовательности

```
randofile = random.choice(flags)
photo = PhotoImage(file = randofile)
```

Comment: не подскажите как к каждой картинке присвоить правильный ответ?

Comment: совершенно не понял вопроса :(

Comment: ответ обязательно приму, но смогу только через пять минут. к примеру это тест. и мне нужно к каждой картинке добавить правильный ответ. как это сделать?

Comment: еще видимо, вопрос и несколько ответов? тогда надо более сложную структуру данных делать, которая будет включать это все в каждый элемент массива